# Implicit getters and setters for a dynamic property in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, getter-setter

When defining an AS3 class, you can use implicit getters and setters to call functions for simple property get/set operations. For example, I could create a temperature class like so:

```
public var celsius:Number;

public function get fahrenheit():Number {
    return 9/5 * celsius + 32;
}

public function set fahrenheit(fahrenheit:Number):void {
    celsius = 5/9 * (fahrenheit - 32);
}
```

Then, I can get/set my temperature in Fahrenheit just like any other property:

```
temperature.fahrenheit = 69.2;
```

This is really useful, but as far as I can tell, it only works for properties declared in a class definition. However, I'd find it extremely useful to be able to define getters and setters on dynamically created properties. Something like this:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj._foo = "bar";
obj.foo = function get () { return this._foo; };
obj.foo = function set (foo:String) { this._foo = foo; };
```

Unfortunately, such syntax does not exist, so my question is this: is it possible to dynamically create property getters and setters in AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. Only using custom oldstyle setters and getters like `setFahrenheit(value:int)` and `getFahrenheit():int`

Comment: And it doesn't really make sense unless you provide a private scope via closure for the decorated field.

Answer (score 7):

Just as an exercise, there is another way one *could* accomplish something similar -- though not directly equivalent -- with one more "indirection". Consider the following code

```
class DynamicProperty {

    private var _getter:Function, _setter:Function;
    private var _source:*, _prop:String;

    public function DynamicProperty(source:*, prop:String, getter:Function, setter:Function):void {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
        _source = source;
        _prop = prop;
    }

    public function get value():* {
        return _getter(_source[_prop]);
    }

    public function set value(val:*):void {
        _source[_prop] = _setter(val);
    }
}
```

This little class takes an instance, the name of a property, and then two functions (a getter and a setter). It provides only one public property, named "value". The public getter and setter are backed by the functions passed in.

And then to use them, you could do something like:

```
       var data:Object = {
           celsius: 0
       };

       data.kelvin = new DynamicProperty(data,"celsius", 
           function(v:Number):Number { return v + 273.15; }, 
           function(v:Number):Number { return v - 273.15; });
```

and then to access `kelvin`, you would use:

```
data.kelvin.value
```

and

```
data.kelvin.value = 0; // absolute zero
```

Now, I'm not suggesting its a great approach, but it's the closest I could think of within the constraints of the language. There are some obvious improvements that one could make, namely abstracting the passed in getters and setters into static methods for reuse. Another thing one might benefit from is, since ActionScript doesn't support user generics, creating specific classes that strongly type the return type of the `value`.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at Proxy class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) to achieve this. Of course, there's no intellisense for such getters and setters. Also, you'd need to extend Proxy class, so any other inheritance that would be fitting the design won't be possible with this class.

Comment: That's honestly really cool, but not quite fitting what I'm looking for, though I'm sure I could get it to work with some modifications. I'll take a look!

Comment: Actually brilliantly exactly what is needed.  Hook that class up to an EventDispatcher, and internalize some Array/Object methods, and you have an event firing object.  I always wondered what use that class was; thank you catholicon!